# I2S communication WS line function

Tags: microphone, i2s, mems-microphone

I was reading the official I2S documentation from Philips and I have some doubts on its functioning (I'm new to this protocol with respect to PDM).

The WS line is used to select either the left or right audio channel. What does this mean in practice? Does it refer to the channels of a single microphones or of two microphones in stereo configuration?

If the microphones are in stereo configuration, how can I assign the left channel to one of the two and the right to the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I2S protocol can transfer 2 channels, so the WS selects which one is currently being transmitted. It does not matter what the channels are, left and right of stereo channel, or two unrelated mono channels.

Now generally I2S uses PCM so it is not PDM.

If you have two mono microphones connected on same I2S bus, then they must somehow know which one is which. They might have a select pin, or you may need to buy two different microphone parts that are configured by the factory which one is which.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. If I may, I still have one doubt. If I would use just one mono microphone, how to deal with the selection pin? Just put it either to GND or Vdd and put the WS always high or low?

Comment: @Luca I can't know what microphone you have and how it works, like which device sends out WS and receives it. But the WS must toggle for each channel as I2S must have two channels per "stereo" sample. Some mono mics could be configured to send same sample for both channels (call them Left and Right for lack of better names).

Comment: I'm planning to use SPH0645LM4H-1 connected to the I2S of a NVIDIA Jeston NANO, and I was wondering if the select pin you previously mentioned must be hardware-tied or software driven, sinchronously with the WS (or even if both are possible)